# Golang slice changed when not modified it

Tags: go

I am new leaner of go, and I try to use it to finish some leetcode problems https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/description/. However I cannot get the right answer, when I try to debug it, I find some variable changed when I do not do any action to it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func get_set(nums []int, can []int, pos int, last_in bool) [][]int{
    if pos == len(nums) {
        res := [][]int{can}
        fmt.Println("Return:")
        fmt.Println(res)
        return res
    }

    f_res := [][]int{}
    if !last_in || ( pos > 0 && nums[pos]!=nums[pos-1] ){
        first_res := get_set(nums,can,pos+1,false)
        fmt.Println("First")
        fmt.Println(first_res)
        f_res = append(f_res,first_res...)
        fmt.Println("f_res")
        fmt.Println(f_res)
    }

    // Problem is here
    fmt.Println("f_res")
    fmt.Println(f_res)
    fmt.Println(can)
    can = append(can,nums[pos])
    fmt.Println(can)
    // Problem is here
    fmt.Println("f_res")
    fmt.Println(f_res)

    second_res := get_set(nums,can,pos+1,true)
    fmt.Println("Second")
    fmt.Println(second_res)
    f_res = append(f_res,second_res...)

    fmt.Println("Total")
    fmt.Println(f_res)
    return f_res
}

func subsetsWithDup(nums []int) [][]int {
    res := make([][]int,0)
    sort.Ints(nums)

    con := make([]int,0)
    res = get_set(nums,con,0,false)
    return res
}

func main()  {
    nums := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
    res := subsetsWithDup(nums)

    fmt.Println(res)
    //for _,l := range res{
    //  fmt.Println(l)
    //}
}
```

The print information is:

```
...
Total
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 5]]
First
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 5]]
f_res
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 5]]
f_res
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 5]]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
f_res
[[1 2 3] [1 2 3 4]]
...
```

Why the variable f_res changed when I append some values to con.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line

```
can = append(can,nums[pos])
```

you are modyfing function argument, which is considered a bad practice. Instead make a new slice and copy the values from the `can` slice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it but it seems not work, and I find the f_res just change in some case